# Does anonymous functions prevent variables from being destroyed by the garbage collector?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, garbage-collection, anonymous-function

I will be using this HTML and JS DOM script as an example, to explain the problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <button id="my-button">Do Something</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let setButtonFunc;

        setButtonFunc = function() {
            let button = document.getElementById("my-button");
            let phrase = "Printing Something";

            button.onclick = function() {
                text = document.createTextNode(phrase);
                document.body.append(text);
            }
        }
        setButtonFunc();
        
        setButtonFunc = null;
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I defined a function `setButtonFunc` into a variable created with the `let` keyword. This function is used to set the button's *onclick* property, enabling it to append text to the page every time its pressed.

**My question is:** will the variables `phrase` and `button` be collected by the Garbage Collector, once the variable `setButtonFunc` is set to *null*?

Logically, all their refereces vanish from that line. Once the variable is set to *null*, only the button's *onclick* function should remain in memory. All the other variables should be collected by the garbage collector, as there are no other references to keep them alive out of scope.

However, if you keep pressing the button, the *onclick* function will keep executing normally as if `phrase` was never released from memory.

I just can't seem to understand it. In python for example, if I were to execute this same example, there would be a time when the garbage collector would destroy the variable and an Exception would be raised.

Why doesn't it happen here with Javascript? Is the anonymous function (used on button's *onclick*) holding their references somehow? Am I missing something from the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the anonymous function (used on button's onclick) holding their references somehow?

This is exactly what is happening and it is called [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Answer (score 1):

button variable should get collected but phrase is still referenced inside click event handler so it will be kept alive as long as the click handler is alive